# State of charge (SOC) and open circuit voltage (OCV) estimation of INR18650 20R Lithium Ion battery

Tags: voltage, lithium-ion, parameters

I want to calculate SOC and OCV of INR18650 20R Lithium Ion battery from CALCE battery dataset available at the website https://calce.umd.edu/battery-data. In a research article I read that  SOC = (discharge capacity/Total capacity)*100 is it correct? I also explore that OCV is the voltage of the battery when no current is flowing. But by considering this logic I obtained an inverse relation between OCV and SOC. Using this dataset. Please guide From these columns of dataset given below how can I calculate OCV and SOC?

```
Step_Time(s)
Step_Index
Cycle_Index
Current(A)
Voltage(v)
Charge_Capacity (AH
Discharge_Capacity(Ah)
Charge_Energy(Wh)
Discharge_Energy(Wh)
```

Comment: user366549 - Hi, You posted a [self-answer](/help/self-answer). Although those are allowed, they must comply with the same rules as any other answer. However the self-answer you posted: (a) Was completely a copy & paste from elsewhere, with no new information. (b) Did not include the [required reference](/help/referencing) when copying (or closely adapting) external material onto Stack Exchange and was therefore plagriarised. || We don't want answers which are mostly or completely copied from elsewhere, and we especially don't want plagiarised material. For these reasons, it was deleted.